# How to add additional information to ember models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am looking to have additional data added onto my models after the JSON data is returned from the service. The service I talk to returns information as a code, but I want to also include a more readable name to display to users. This would be done almost everywhere the model is used.

Example:

Fetch from the service

```
{schedule: {code:'MONTHLY'}}
```

Have access to

```
{schedule: {code:'MONTHLY', name: 'Monthly'}}
```

This would be for things which have a map of code to name, where name only ever lives on the front end, and code is what is persisted. I see there is a concept of [custom transforms](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/models/defining-models/#toc_custom-transforms), would this be the way to go?

I also plan to keep a mapping of all possible codes/names in another file, to iterate over or compare to the model's attributes. For instance I would want to present users with a choice of schedules to choose from, MONTHLY, QUARTERLY, or ANNUALLY.

Comment: You can write computed property inside model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a Computed Property on a model. You can call it: "name" or "displayName". It should depend on "code" attribute on model. Inside computed property, you should access a service. Service should have a method to map code -> name. A method you call from the model on service should return you a name. A code-name map should be separated from the model.

Whenever you want to access `displayName` Computed Property from model use `model.displayName`.